# srand not random at all - alternatives?

Tags: c++, random, srand

I was toying around with arrays, populating with pseudo random numbers, finding minimum and maximum values and their indices and number of occurrences and I noticed something strange - **when using srand seeded with time the number of minimum and maximum value occurrences is ALWAYS equal**. This doesn't seem very random to me.

**Is there an alternative way of getting a DIFFERENT number of minimum and maximum value occurrences, as one would expect with random numbers?**

Here is my code (I am learning so it may be messy and inefficient, recommendations are welcome)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void findExtremes( const int[], int); 

int main()
{
    const int lenght = 2000; //define lenght

    int array1[lenght];

    srand(time(0)); 

    for ( int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) //populate array with random numbers and print them out
    {
        array1[i] = rand() % 3000;
        cout << "Index " << i << " = " << array1[i] << endl;
    }

    findExtremes(array1, lenght);   // call fn

    return 0;
}

void findExtremes( const int array[], int size)
{
     int maxV, minV, maxI, minI;
     maxV = array[0];
     minV = array[0];
     minI = 0;
     maxI = 0;

     for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++)
     {
         if ( array[i] > maxV)
            {
                maxV = array[i];
                maxI = i;
            }
         if ( array[i] < minV)
            {
                minV = array[i];
                minI = i;
            }
     }

     //find the number of occurances for min and max values

     int minOcc = 0;
     int maxOcc = 0;

     for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++)
     {
             if (array[i] == minV)
                 minOcc++;
             if (array[i] == minV)
                 maxOcc++;
     }

     //output

     cout << "\nMinmim value is index " << minI << " with value " << minV << " and " << minOcc << " occurances" << endl;
     cout << "\nMaxium value is index " << maxI << " with value " << maxV << " and " << maxOcc << " occurances" << endl << "\n";  
}
```

Comment: rand() is based on a pseudo-random function. So there's a lot of chance it will not be that random. If you need strong random values, you need to search for cryptographic random number generator, as most encryption algorithm is based on really strong generator

Comment: you are comparing two times with minV (when finding occurences)

Comment: Thank you DeyyyFF, I totally pwned myself. 

Please close the question. I feel stupid and ashamed :)

Lazy copy and paste is bad practice apparently...

Comment: I don't think that the question should be closed. Most answers are simply wrong with regards the the random number generation and the seeding. The question has still its value because a lot of people felt into the same trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, they're actually *pseudo* random numbers, not random numbers. In any case, it may be that a a truly random sequence has that exact property that you're seeing :-) The sequence `1,1,1,1,1` is as equally likely to occur in a truly random set as much as `5,2,4,2,99`.

If you want a "more random" random sequence, I wouldn't be using the normal ones shipped with C libraries (unless those libraries were written by people who understand randomness) - you should look into things like the Mersenne Twister, using `/dev/random` (if under Linux) and so on.

You may also want to look at this snippet of your code.

```
if (array[i] == minV)
    minOcc++;
if (array[i] == minV)
    maxOcc++;
```

I believe that last `if` should be comparing with `maxV` rather than `minV`. Otherwise there is zero chance that your minimum and maximum counts will be different.

When I make that change (and change `% 3000` to `% 30`, to get a range of duplicates), I see:

```
Minmim value is index 112 with value 0 and 65 occurances
Maxium value is index 24 with value 29 and 58 occurances
```

---

And, not that it really matters in terms of this question, you may want to clean up your spelling somewhat:

- `lenght` -> `length`.
- `minmum` -> `minimum`
- `maxium` -> `maximum`
- `occurances` -> `occurrences`

Comment: Mersenne Twister has uniform distribution, just the same. It does have a larger state leading to a longer period of pseudo randomness.

Comment: Once again, lazy and hasty copy/paste is to blame, as for the spelling, even thou I am not a native speaker I actually know the right spelling of those, just didn't really pay any attention to what I put in "" - it wasn't even supposed to be seen by others until that lazy paste mistake drove me here. It is all working as it  should now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I perform numerical simulations on Physics and my group uses the [GSL library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html) for that:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

class Random
{
private:
    gsl_rng* r; //!< Pointer to the gsl rng
public:
    //! Constructor: uses argument as the seed
    Random(long unsigned int seed);

    long int R(int N);
    long double R();
    long double gaussianR(long double sigma);
};

inline Random::Random(long unsigned int s)
{
    r = gsl_rng_alloc( gsl_rng_taus );
    gsl_rng_set(r, s); //seed to use to the pseudo-aleatory number generator.
}

// a uniform number between 0 and N-1
inline long int Random::R(int N)
{
    return gsl_rng_uniform_int (r, N);
}

// a uniform number between 0 and 1
inline long double Random::R()
{
    return gsl_rng_uniform_pos( r );
}

// a gaussian distribution with sigma
inline long double Random::gaussianR(long double sigma)
{
    return gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma);
}
```

you have to compile it with flags:
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas

and add includes and libs (this is for fink installation case):

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = /sw/include
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = /sw/lib

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Gentlepeople: NOTE**
>
> Yes! This answer is "old". And in the era of c++11, by all means use c++11 `<random>`. But **please** don't downvote this question, years after the fact because you think "*Ew* Everybody *knows* `rand()` is evil!". In fact, it is not. It's just limited, and very easy to use inappropriately. **But** - as an historic fact, it exists as an API and it is *still* useful to document how you can use it *better*. I'm not deleting this answer for very reason.
>
> Original answer:
>
> ---

Please read

http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Notably, don't write `rand() % 3000`. Write

```
 int r = rand() / ( RAND_MAX / 3000 + 1 );
```

In fact, random should be uniformly distributed, meaning that indeed the lower and upper bound would have near 100% chance of occurring when the number of samples is large enough (larger than the size of the domain, for starters).

That's what true random is about (try to do a Monte-Carlo algorithm without it - you'd be very unhappy)

Comment: People looking for more up-to-date advice are invited to look at a [random (... ☺) selection of my other answers involving random in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20%22%3crandom%3e%22%20-srand)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `random` library included in C++11, or you can use the Boost::Random library that it was based off.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your initial statement is wrong. **The code is provides different numbers each time**. I tried you unmodified code and there are the results:

```
Minmim value is index 1194 with value 0 and 1 occurances
Maxium value is index 1264 with value 2995 and 1 occurances

Minmim value is index 1958 with value 1 and 1 occurances
Maxium value is index 1510 with value 2991 and 1 occurances

...
```

However, there are two bugs in the code:

- In the second for loop, you should start with i = 0.
- You should compare with maxV instead of minV in the same loop.

With regards to the random number generation:

- When seeded with the *same number*, a *series of rand() calles should return the same numbers*. rand() is not for random numbers, but for pseudo-random numbers. rand() should be have this way because than e.g. a simulation will output the same results when started with the same seed. It is a very nice property.
- You *seed it with the current time*, which is ok and therefore rand() should return a *different series of numbers each time* (at least when not called multiple times a second). The seeding looks good to me. It is in fact very similar to the example provided [here](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/srand.html).
- The sample size is 2000 and the range of generated numbers is 3000. This means that it is not probable that the minimal size and the maximal size are always the same. If the sample size would be a million, with a high probability 2999 should be the largest number in the very most runs.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of your Pseudo-Random Number Generator (PRNG) is perfectly normal.

In fact, if your draw enough numbers from `rand()`, you will always get the same extrema, since it is uniformly distributed.

In your case, the question is: **do you need another behaviour**? You should not pounce on True Random Numbers as @sehe suggests. This might be useless, and even problematic when dealing with stochastic simulations, which Monte Carlo algorithms are. Imagine that you want to debug a code snippet based upon random numbers, or that of colleague of yours intends to check your results: **how would you do if you were not able to reproduce the same random sequence?**

That is one of the reason why PRNGs are sufficient and often preferred when you do not need crypto-secure random numbers.